# Pathwise measurability of Ito integral under supremum norm

Tags: stochastic-integrals, holder-spaces, wiener-measure

I'm doing my first research project on Stochastic Analysis and in order to prove something which is crucial, I need to prove the following claim:

LEMMA:

Denote by $(C_{0}[0,\,T],\,||\centerdot||_{\infty},\,\mathcal{B})$
the classical Wiener space of continuous paths defined on $[0,\,T]$
and started at zero, equipped the supremum norm $||\centerdot||_{\infty}$
and the corresponding Borel sigma algebra $\mathcal{B}$.

For an $m-$dimensional
Brownian motion, consider the n-dimensional SDE:
$
X_{t}=X_{0}+\int_{0}^{t}a(s,\,X_{s})ds+\int_{0}^{t}b(s,\,X_{s})dB_{s},\,0\leq t\leq T$

where the random variable $X_{0}$ and the coefficients $a,\,b$ have a very good regularity (as good as we want).

For each
Brownian path $B_{.}:=\{B_{t}\}_{0\leq t\leq T}$ and realization
$x$ of the random variable $X_{0}$, denote by $f(B_{.},\,x)$ the
corresponding path of the pathwise unique strong solution to the above
SDE, which is given by Ito's theorem.

Then the map $f$ which maps
the product space $(C_{0}[0,\,T])^{m}\times\mathbb{R}^{n}$ to the
product space $(C_{0}[0,\,T])^{n}$ is measurable with the product
topologies.

.
.
.
.
.

I have searched a lot, but I have been unable to find something relevant. Working with Rough path theory, we find that this result is true if we replace the supremum norm with the a-Holer norm. However this does not help, because I want the preimages to be measurable with the Wiener probability measure, and again this is something I'm unable to prove or disprove. Can anyone help?

Thank you in advance.